# InstrumentationKey not picked up when stored in key vault

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework, azure-keyvault

I am using a `key-vault` to store all the keys used in my `bot v4` solution. I suspect the InstrumentationKey is not picked up correctly. What should be the name of the ApplicationInsights- InstrumentationKey in the key-vault.

In appsetting.json the key is added like this :

```
 "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx"   }.
```

Comment: How about `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY`?

Comment: @IvanYang KeyVault doesn't accept '_'

Comment: what's the code you're using to read it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. These were the steps I followed to resolve it in an ASP.NET Core MVC 5 application:

- In **Program.cs** file, the code for adding configuration values from Key Vault in Production environment (based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources):

  ```
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
           {
               if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
               {
                   var builtConfig = config.Build();

                   var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                   var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                       new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                           azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                   config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                       $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                       keyVaultClient,
                       new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
               }
           })
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
  ```
- In **Azure Key Vault** create a new secret with the name "**ApplicationInsights--InstrumentationKey**" and give it the value of the production application insights instrumentation key. In order for your app service to be able to communicate with the key vault and read the secrets, you need to firstly **enable the system assigned service identity for your azure app service** and then create a **key vault Access Policy for Get, List operations for secrets** and assign the policy to the previously created **system assigned service identity**.
- In **appSettings.Production.json** file:

  ```
   {
    "Logging": {
       "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
       }
     },
     "KeyVaultName": "{your-keyvault-name}",
     "ApplicationInsights": {
       "CloudRoleName": "TinyCrm.Web.Prod",
       "DisableTelemetry": false,
       "EnableAdaptiveSampling": true
     }
   }
  ```
- To register the application insights specific stuff for the aspnet core DI framework I created the following extension method. I am using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspnetCore version 2.17.0 nuget package. (taking into consideration what is written here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#user-secrets-and-other-configuration-providers):

  ```
   public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationInsights(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       // Register the settings for "ApplicationInsights" section as a service for injection from DI container
       var applicationInsightsSettings = new ApplicationInsightsSettings();
       configuration.Bind(ApplicationInsightsSettings.ApplicationInsightsSectionKey, applicationInsightsSettings);
       services.AddSingleton(applicationInsightsSettings);

       // Use telemetry initializers when you want to enrich telemetry with additional information
       services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CloudRoleTelemetryInitializer>();

       // Remove a specific built-in telemetry initializer
       var telemetryInitializerToRemove = services.FirstOrDefault<ServiceDescriptor>
                           (t => t.ImplementationType == typeof(AspNetCoreEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer));

       if (telemetryInitializerToRemove != null)
       {
           services.Remove(telemetryInitializerToRemove);
       }

       // You can add custom telemetry processors to TelemetryConfiguration by using the extension method AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor on IServiceCollection. 
       // You use telemetry processors in advanced filtering scenarios
       services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<StaticWebAssetsTelemetryProcessor>();

       // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
       services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

       return services;
   }
  ```
- In **Startup.cs** file:

  ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddControllersWithViews();

       // Call the extension method we created above
       services.AddApplicationInsights(Configuration);
   }
  ```
- **Important note**: Make sure when you create the new Azure App Service to **not enable the Application Insights Telemetry integration automatically from the Azure app service creation wizard** (see below image). Instead create the application insights resource yourself and setup your app to use the instrumentation key in production environment through following the above steps.

[Azure App Service Creation Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIRsQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The name set in Azure Key Vault for the secret is relative to what naming convention you used in your app settings json file.

Below is a working example from my own appsettings.json file:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "<SetByKeyVault>",
    "IngestionEndpoint": "https://uksouth-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/",
}
```

And below is the secret for the Instrumentation key in Key Vault:

[image]

The two dots shown above in between "ApplicationInsights" and "InstrumentationKey" is just a way of the Key Vault being able to find it's way to the inner property of the object shown in app settings json file. The general documentation on Key Vaults will cover this detail with a better explanation on this than mine.

One of the gotchas for me was remembering that Key vault secrets does not accept certain characters, I was attempting to save the full connection string as a secret in the Key Vault which would have made life easier rather than having to string together the pieces to make up the full connection string within my NET Core app, but soon realised this wasnt going to work. So, I just stored the instrumentation key itself in Key Vault (the bit we dont want to expose for security reasons) and then I built up the rest of the connection string within my app:

NET Core 7 Web App Program.cs file:

```
// Create the connection string for App Insights.
var appInsightConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey="
    + builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"] 
    + ";IngestionEndpoint=" 
    + builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:IngestionEndpoint"];

// Quick code sample below for writing an event to app insigts 
// during .Net Core startup (likely different in your environment)

TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
using var telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration();
telemetryConfiguration.ConnectionString = appInsightConnectionString;
telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);

var logEvent = new LogEvent
{
    OhiAppSource = "Web Application Client",
    LogEventCategory = "WebApp-CLIENT",
    LogEventType = "Application Startup",
    LogEventSource = "System",
    LogData = "Application Starting Up"
};

logEvent.LogLevel = "Information";
telemetryClient.TrackTrace(JsonSerializer.Serialize(logEvent), SeverityLevel.Information);
```